# Pass multimap to new Thread?

Tags: c++, pthreads, multimap

is there a possibility to pass the whole content of a multimap to a new Thread, or maybe pass the multimap itself as an argument to the Thread, like:

```
pthread_create(&new_thread, NULL, thread_name, (void*) multimap);
```

Thanks!

Comment: yes, but you need to take the address of the multimap before casting it to void*, as in (void*)&multimap, assuming multimap is an object in the calling context with a lifetime longer than it's use in the thread.  Alternatively, you can pass a pointer to a dynamically allocated multimap and leave the thread to delete it when finished (i.e. a transfer of ownership)

Comment: The multimap gets new values very often (ms) and should update this values to the thread.

Comment: "update this values to the thread" - do you mean the updates should be visible in the thread that ran `pthread_create`?  If so, then having the latter thread own the object is reasonable (or a shared pointer could be used).  Anyway, your usage just requires all access to the multimap (after the `pthread_create`) be coordinated using a mutex or rw-lock around.